# Why is the task status always running when the HDFS server in NebulaGraph Explorer cannot be connected?

Tags: nebula-graph

Sometimes the explorer fails to connect to the HDFS because of network fluctuations. In this case, the task status is always running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the timeout period for HDFS connections as follows:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>ipc.client.connect.timeout</name>
    <value>3000</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>ipc.client.connect.max.retries.on.timeouts</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```